# How to check whether a point is inside the black regions or not?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, non-convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

I have a huge map which is similar to bellow,
[image]

Problem:

I want to find feasible path between two points in the map. Since size of map is huge it takes enormous time to calculate the path. The knowledge I have is that **black regions are defined by a set of polytopes**.

Is there faster way to determine whether a given point is inside a black regions or not? I am asking this because path path planning algorithm takes time to decide given point is obstacle-free or not due size of map.

Comment: Store the black regions in a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) so that you cut down on the number of black regions you need to test.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I will try and let you know thank youu

Comment: All your black "dots" look pretty similar. You say they are generated as polytopes ; do you have any idea about the vectors generating them ?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I tried quadtree and KD-tree but still it takes huge time

Comment: @JeanMarie I am not sure I understand you, polytope are generated as set of points which define the verticies

Comment: You're going to have to measure what exactly is taking such a long time. Is it that the path algorithm is slow because it tests a lot of points? Is your point test slow because it is checking out too many black regions? (the qaudtree should have helped with that) Is checking a single black region slow because the region has so many sides? If it is this last issue, and the black polygons are all the same shape (or a few shapes), then you can again use a quadtree, this time  to capture the shape so that you only test the point against at most two sides. Or find some other polygon test algorithm.

Comment: 1) Therefore, the term polytope should be replaced by "convex hull" of points. 2) Can the puzzling fact that the dots are very similar (as I made the remark above) be explained ? Indeed this property could hopefully be exploited to spare a lot of testing.

Comment: Perhaps solve the problem for a lower-resolution version of the map, and only increase the resolution when necessary (not sure if there is a path)

Comment: @TomKern I was thinking about that, but now kind of trying  Mixed-Integer planning let's see how thing goes?

Comment: Could you answer my question ?

Comment: You hopefuly know "mathematical morphology": this figure is typical of a set that has undergone a dilation.

Comment: @JeanMarie really sorry, yeap black dots are similar, but not clear how to create a convex hull, Yeap I am thinking how to use this property to make an educated guess. However, still no luck (;

Comment: Anyway thank you all of you for trying to help me :)